# fetching database data in datagridview using backgroundworker in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

After fetching data from database in datagridview last data is repeated but missed the first data in datagridview. I follow this link https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1148/datagrid-using-backgroundworker-c-sharp

```
     private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        RetriveTableData Obj = (RetriveTableData)e.Argument;

        string SqlcmdString = "SELECT * from tblBook";

        SqlDataReader reader;
        int i = 1;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                Sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(SqlcmdString, conn);
                conn.Open();
                reader = Sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //int.Parse(reader["NO_IND"].ToString());
                      //  Obj.EmpId = reader["C_FICH"].ToString();
                     //   Obj.EmpName = reader["C_SITE"].ToString();
                        Obj.AccessionNo = reader["accessionNo"].ToString();
                        Obj.Author = reader["author"].ToString();

                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        // To Report progress.
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i, Obj);

                        if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
                        {
                            // Set the e.Cancel flag so that the WorkerCompleted event
                            // knows that the process was cancelled.
                            e.Cancel = true;
                            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0);
                            return;
                        }
                        i++;
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public class RetriveTableData
    {
        public string AccessionNo;
        public string Author;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
        {
            //Gets the user state that is sent as part of ReportProgress() Method from DoWork Event 
            RetriveTableData Obj = (RetriveTableData)e.UserState;
            //Add the data to the dataGridView1
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(Obj.AccessionNo.ToString(), Obj.Author.ToString());
           progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
           label1.Text = "Processing row.. " + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + " of " + TotalRecords;
        }

    }
    private int GetTotalRecords()
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd;
        try
        {
            using (con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblBook", con);
                con.Open();
                TotalRecords = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return TotalRecords;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            label1.Text = "Cancelled by User Intentionally...";
         progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
        // Check to see if an error occurred in the background process. 
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
           label1.Text = e.Error.Message;
        }
        else
        {
            // BackGround Task Completed with out Error
           label1.Text = " All Records Loaded...";
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // statusStrip1.Visible = true;
        // toolStripStatusLabel1.Visible = true;


        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 2;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Access No.";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Width = 150;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Width = 150;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth = 21;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode =  DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight = 23;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Author";


        progressBar1.Maximum = GetTotalRecords();

        if (!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
        {
            RetriveTableData TObj = new RetriveTableData();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            // Start the BackGround Thread to Execute
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(TObj);
          //  btStart.Enabled = false;
            //btCancel.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

I got this  output where the firstdata: 1122 is missed out and last data PEC-5281 is repeated. Due to my low level i couldnot post image so i put link where you can view the output.

https://krishnas.com.np/2.PNG

Comment: You only have 1 Obj, and you're getting it in a strange way.

Comment: what does it mean. I can't understand what you reply

Comment: you have to create a new obj inside the while-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need create a collection of objects for every row nad then use that collection as data source of `DataGridView`

With `async-await` it can be done little bid clearer and without extra thread created by `BackgroundWorker`

```
 private async Task<IEnumerable<RetriveTableData>> GetDataAsync()
 {
    var query = "SELECT * from tblBook";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
        {
            var data = new List<RetriveTableData>();
            while(await reader.ReadAsync())
            {
                var temp = new RetriveTableData
                {
                    EmpId = reader["C_FICH"].ToString();
                    EmpName = reader["C_SITE"].ToString();
                    AccessionNo = reader["accessionNo"].ToString();
                    Obj.Author = reader["author"].ToString();
                };

                data.Add(temp);
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

Then for example in `Form.Load` eventhandler you can load data.

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = await GetDataAsync();
}
```